# Sum of mysql column multiplied by a variable within php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a hobby developer and i've run into a snag that I've tried to fix for a few days now, so I would first like to thank anyone in advance who can help.

I'm trying to display a the following result via php.

> (nb - history_points has a conversion of 10,000 to $1)

```
$get_earned = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(history_points) FROM activity_history") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_earned)){
$total_points = $row['SUM(history_points)'];
```

The result is

```
SUM ( `history_points`)
 218903.0000
```

I then display this result using:

```
 php echo "$".convert(number_format($total_points));
```

Now the issue is it get's displayed as `$0.0218` when it should read `$21.89`

I have tried the following, which displays $0, where 10000 is the points to usd conversion.

```
$get_earned = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(history_points * 10000) FROM activity_history") or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm completley at a loss.

Comment: What is `convert()`?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` doesn't work with `mysql_error()`. Different APIs.

Comment: You're mixing mysql APIs. If you get an error that won't work.

Comment: `number_format(218903.0000)` results in `218,903`. So it is probably your mysterious `convert` function here that messes this up.

Answer (score 2):

When you are changing your query to:

```
"SELECT SUM(history_points * 10000) FROM activity_history"
```

the column name would also change, for which you'll have to fetch correct value in php.

```
$total_points = $row['SUM(history_points * 10000)'];
```

As per @pritaeas suggestion, better use an alias.

```
"SELECT SUM(history_points * 10000) as ABC FROM activity_history"

$total_points = $row['ABC'];
```

Comment: Or use an alias: `SELECT SUM(history_points * 10000) AS history_points_sum FROM activity_history`

Comment: Yes. That would be better. Updated the answer.

Comment: I've tried this soloution and recieve Http Error 500, I've tried to remove the .convert(number_format) section as stated above,

I've also removed all mysql and only left the mysqli (I didn't write this script, I'm trying to fix it :p)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$get_earned = mysqli_query ( $conn, "SELECT SUM(history_points) FROM activity_history" ) or die ( mysql_error () );
$total_points = 0;
if ($get_earned !== false) {
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $get_earned )) {
        $total_points = $row [0];
    }
}

// If you need to multiply the total by a variable in php, then simply multiply it:
if ($total_points !== 0) {
    $constant_var = 7;//just an example, it's ur constant
    echo "$" . number_format ( $constant_var * $total_points, 2 );
}
```

Comment: try to display it without number_format, `echo "$" .  ( $constant_var * $total_points ); ` and are you sure that you are getting the SUM(history_points) correct from the DB? how did you know it was 218903.0000 ?

Comment: we need to make sure that you're getting correct result from your query